# Wifi switch always disabled in HP250 G3. (Ubuntu 16.04 LTE)

Tags: networking, wireless, ralink

I recently installed ubunu 16.04 LTS. The wired connections work perfectly, but the wireless connection (wifi) does not work. I tried pressing the wifi switch (f12), also (fn+f12). But the switch is always red and would not enable. I already saw the hard disabled and the soft disabled thing, it says both hard and soft disabled. Please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Here's the output for lsmod

```
    $ lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
    nls_utf8               16384  0
    isofs                  40960  0
    nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
    arc4                   16384  2
    intel_rapl             20480  0
    rt2800pci              16384  0
    rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
    rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
    rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
    rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
    x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
    rt2x00lib              57344  5 
    rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
    intel_powerclamp       16384  0
    coretemp               16384  0
    mac80211              737280  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
    kvm_intel             172032  0
    kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
    uvcvideo               90112  0
    irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
    cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
    videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
    crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
    videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
    snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
    videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
    crc32_pclmul           16384  0
    hp_wmi                 16384  0
    videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
    snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
    v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
    aesni_intel           167936  0
    aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
    videodev              176128  4  
    uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
    media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
    snd_hda_intel          36864  5
    lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
    gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
    glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
    rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
    ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
    eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
    snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
    cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
    memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
    snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
    crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
    snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
    snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
    snd_seq_midi           16384  0
    snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
    joydev                 20480  0
    input_leds             16384  0
    snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
    lpc_ich                24576  0
    serio_raw              16384  0
    snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
    snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
    8250_dw                16384  0
    snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
    soundcore              16384  1 snd
    dw_dmac                16384  0
    mei_me                 36864  0
    dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
    i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
    mei                    98304  1 mei_me
    i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
    spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
    intel_hid              16384  0
    hp_wireless            16384  0
    shpchp                 36864  0
    soc_button_array       16384  0
    sparse_keymap          16384  2 hp_wmi,intel_hid
    mac_hid                16384  0
    parport_pc             32768  0
    ppdev                  20480  0
    lp                     20480  0
    parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
    autofs4                40960  2
    uas                    24576  0
    usb_storage            69632  2 uas
    rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
    ahci                   36864  6
    nouveau              1495040  1
    libahci                32768  1 ahci
    i915                 1208320  4
    psmouse               126976  0
    mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
    rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
    i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
    ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
    drm_kms_helper        147456  2 i915,nouveau
    syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    drm                   360448  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
    r8169                  81920  0
    mii                    16384  1 r8169
    i2c_hid                20480  0
    video                  40960  2 i915,nouveau
    hid                   118784  1 i2c_hid
    sdhci_acpi             16384  0
    wmi                    20480  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
    sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
    fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lsmod | egrep 'asus|acer'`

Comment: Do the function buttons work for other applications? It could be a keyboard/hardware problem with your installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: yeah ... the function buttons work fine. In fact, i got my keyboard replaced last week. Other control functions like volume up/down, etc are working and i'm able to see the LEDs. But somehow, the switch for the wifi doesn't seem to work. I even tried installing the drivers, but it made it even worse! I was not able to see any wifi options after installing it.

Comment: @Jeremy31... I've edited the question. You can see the entire details now.